# Unable to retrieve historical snapshot dates in Apex

Tags: reporting, reports-api, analytic-snapshots

I'm trying to find a way to query information in Apex regarding AnalyticSnapshots ("Reporting Snapshots" in the UI). The object itself isn't queryable via SOQL, but I thought I might have found a workaround with the following:

```
Reports.ReportManager.describeReport('<idOfMyReport>').getReportMetadata().getHistoricalSnapshotDates();
```

...where  is the id of a Report that is the source for a reporting snapshot. I have verified the snapshots are running for this report; I see the history in Setup UI.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm) on this method are quite light on details. Wondering if anyone here can shed light on whether the meaning of "historical snapshots" is referencing Reporting Snapshots, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referencing are Historical Dates that you can setup (up to 5 dates) to compare values with Historical Trend reports.

What you are looking for is [AnalyticSnapshot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_analyticsnapshot.htm), but I'm not aware how ot retrieve a history of all runs.

All I know that `Reporting Snapshot Name`, `Reporting Snapshot Running User`, `Execution Time` can be added to each Snapshot record (on a Custom Object) that can be used to run SOQL to get some statistics.

Answer (score 1):

There is the dedicated Analytics REST API that mentions report snapshots in relation to the [`/wave/trendedreports` resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_trendedtreports_id.htm).

It isn't entirely clear if trendedreports are Reporting Snapshots or something else entirely. Reporting Snapshots have the keyprefix 0A0 (ReportJob).

I tried quickly in my dev org. While I could create the a Reporting Snapshot the REST API returned the error:

> /services/data/v41.0/wave/trendedreports

```
[ {
  "message" : "This feature is not currently enabled for this user type or org: [Wave]",
  "errorCode" : "FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED"
} ]
```